# Counter in C Programming

Tags: c

I am trying to set up a counter for my programme to count how many times a signal was sent. I am trying to achieve the program to exit after ctrl +c was pressed twice. I have most of the code but just don't know how to link the counter to the if section. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// user-defined signal handler for alarm.

int cnt=0; 

void my_handler(int signo)
{
    while ( cnt < 2){
        if (signo == SIGINT)
        {
            printf("Press ctrl c to stop\n");

            exit(0);

        }
    }
} 

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGINT,my_handler);
    while(1){ 
        printf(" I am running into infinite loop.., stop me if you dear..\n");
        sleep(1); /* wait until alarm goes off */
    }
} /* main */
```

I tried out the above code and it seems that the counter will stay at 0 forever and the programme exit immediately as soon as ctrl+c was pressed.

Comment: if `cnt` is your counter... you need to add something to it, like `cnt++;` or `cnt+=1;` or `cnt = cnt+1;` which are all equivalent if they are alone in a statement

Comment: also the name `cnt` makes me a little uneasy...

Comment: You really don't want that `while` loop in your signal handler.  Realize that, each time you press control-C, your signal handler will typically get called, do its thing, *and return*.  It's true that, at the top level, you could use the English words "the program keeps running *while* the count is less than 2" to describe what you're trying to do here, but that's just not the way you express it in a procedural (imperative) language like C.  In this case, you want to have the signal handler exit (instead of returning) *if* the count is greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: @GradyPlayer  
i had changed the code from while ( cnt < 2) to if (cnt++ <2) the programme stop at the forth time rather than the second time. Why is that?  I now change the 2 to a 0 and the programme stop at the second time!! why is that?

Answer (score 2):

[You can't do much safely in a `signal` handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling#Handling), and definitely no I/O. For maximum portability, there are really only a handful of things a `signal` handler can do to affect global state:

1. Assign to a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable
2. Make calls to `signal`
3. `abort`, `exit`, etc. on error

You can't do I/O safely. The safe thing to do is set a flag that the main thread can check and do your printing for you. If printing isn't necessary, the first call to your handler could just unregister itself, restoring the default behavior with `SIG_DFL` (or registering a new "second Ctrl-C" handler if you need to do something special) so the second Ctrl-C kills as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the while statement with an if one. If `cnt` is lower than 2, then print your message and count by using `cnt++;` else do something else

Answer (score 0):

Signals are a little more involved to get right.

You should either use `sigaction` or a custom sigaction wrapper as signal doesn't have clearly defined semantics. Registering the handler may fail.
If you want to set a flag, it should be `volatile sigatomic_t`, you shouldn't do buffered IO in the handler.

With the wrapper and flag approach, you could do something like:

```
typedef void (Sigfunc)(int);
Sigfunc* reliableSignal(int signo, Sigfunc *func);

// user-defined signal handler for alarm.

volatile sig_atomic_t cnt=0; 


void my_handler(int signo){
  if(cnt++ == 1)
    exit(0);
} 

int main(void) {
  if(reliableSignal(SIGINT,my_handler)<0){ perror("Signal"); exit(1); }
  while(1){ 
    printf(" I am running into infinite loop.., stop me if you dear..\n");
    sleep(1); /* wait until alarm goes off */
  }
} /* main */

Sigfunc* reliableSignal(int signo, Sigfunc *func)
{
  struct sigaction act, oact;
    act.sa_handler = func;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags = 0;
  if (signo == SIGALRM) {
#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
    act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif
  } else {
    act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
  }
  if (sigaction(signo, &act, &oact) < 0)
    return(SIG_ERR);
  return(oact.sa_handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example you must press **twice** Ctrl-C within 300ms.

So if you keep Ctrl-C pressed the program will stop otherwise not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int ctrlcs=0;

void cchandler(int signum){
  printf("Press again to quit.\n");
  ctrlcs+=1;
  if (ctrlcs==2) {
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
  } 
  usleep(300000);  // delay for the second Ctrl-C
}

int main(){

  signal(SIGINT, cchandler);

  while(1) {
   printf(" I am running into infinite loop.., stop me if you dare..\n");
   sleep (5);
   ctrlcs=0;
  }

}
```